# SKSpriteNode isn't responding when I try to hide it (Spoiler: SKAction timing issue)

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode, skaction

OK, so I've been working on doing an RPG-style dialog box for a project, and while most of it is going smoothly, the one thing that's tripping me up right now is the little icon in the corner of the box to let you know there's more.

I tried to figure out how to get draw the shape, but not having any luck getting Core Graphics to draw triangles I decided to just use a PNG image of one instead.  The code below shows everything relevant to how it's been set up and managed.

That being figured out, I'm now trying to get it to hide the marker when updating the box and show it again afterward.  Here's what I've tried so far:

1. **Method 1:** Use `.alpha = 0` to hide it from view during updates, restore with `.alpha = 1`
2. **Method 2:** Remove it from the node tree
3. **Method 3:** Place it behind the box background (located at `.zPosition = -1`)

The result has been consistent across all 3 methods: The triangle just stays in place, unresponsive when invoked.

```swift
class DialogBox: SKNode {
    private var continueMarker = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "continueTriangle") // The triangle that shows in the lower-right to show there's more to read

    init() {
        /// Setup and placement.  It appears in the proper position if I draw it and don't try to hide anything
        continueMarker.size.width = 50
        continueMarker.size.height = 25
        continueMarker.position = CGPoint(x: ((width / 2) - (continueMarker.size.width * 0.9)), y: ((continueMarker.size.height * 0.9) - (height - margin)))
        addChild(continueMarker)
    }

    func updateContent(forceAnimation: Bool = false) {
        /// Determine what content to put into the box
        
        hideContinueMarker()
        
        /// Perform the content update in the box (which works as it should)
        
        showContinueMarker()
    }

    func showContinueMarker() {
//      continueMarker.alpha = 1 /// Method 1: Use .alpha to hide it from view during updates

//      if (continueMarker.parent == nil) { // Method 2: Remove it from the tree
//          addChild(continueMarker)
//      }

        continueMarker.zPosition = -2 /// Method 3: place it behind the box background (zPosition -1)
    }
    
    func hideContinueMarker() {
//      continueMarker.alpha = 0 /// Method 1

//      if (continueMarker.parent != nil) { /// Method 2
//          continueMarker.removeFromParent()
//      }

        continueMarker.zPosition = 2 /// Method 3
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, so while typing this one up I had some more ideas and ended up solving my own problem, so I figured I'd share the solution here, rather than pull a DenverCoder9 on everyone.

On the plus side, you get a look at a simple way to animate text in SpriteKit!  Hooray!

In a final check to make sure I wasn't losing my mind, I added some print statements to `showContinueMarker()` and `hideContinueMarker()` and noticed that they **always** appeared simultaneously.

What's that mean?  `SKAction` is likely at fault.  Here's a look at the code for animating updates to the box:

```swift
    private func animatedContentUpdate(contentBody: String, speaker: String? = nil) {
        if let speaker = speaker {
            // Update speaker box, if provided
            speakerLabel.text = speaker
        }

        var updatedText = "" // Text shown so far
        var actionSequence: [SKAction] = []
        
        for char in contentBody {
            updatedText += "\(char)"
            
            dialogTextLabel.text = updatedText

            // Set up a custom action to update the label with the new text         
            let updateLabelAction = SKAction.customAction(withDuration: animateUpdateSpeed.rawValue, actionBlock: { [weak self, updatedText] (node, elapsed) in
                self?.dialogTextLabel.text = updatedText
            })
            
            // Queue up the action so we can run the batch afterward
            actionSequence.append(updateLabelAction)
        }
        
        /// HERE'S THE FIX
        // We needed to add another action to the end of the sequence so that showing the marker again didn't occur concurrent with the update sequence.
        let showMarker = SKAction.customAction(withDuration: animateUpdateSpeed.rawValue, actionBlock: { [weak self] (node, elapsed) in
            self?.showContinueMarker()
        })
        
        // Run the sequence
        actionSequence.append(showMarker)
        
        removeAction(forKey: "animatedUpdate") // Cancel any animated updates already in progress
        run(SKAction.sequence(actionSequence), withKey: "animatedUpdate") // Start the update
    }
```

In case you missed it in the big block there, here's the specific bit in isolation

```swift
let showMarker = SKAction.customAction(withDuration: animateUpdateSpeed.rawValue, actionBlock: { [weak self] (node, elapsed) in
    self?.showContinueMarker()
})
```

Basically, we needed to add showing the triangle as an action at the end of the update sequence instead of just assuming it would occur after the update since the function was invoked at a later time.

And since all 3 methods work equally well now that the timing has been fixed, I've gone back to the `.alpha = 0` method to keep it simple.